# What's behind Excel Solver Evolutionary?

Tags: excel, solver, evolutionary-algorithm

I have an optimization problem on Excel, using Evolutionary algorithm.
Works fine, but i'd like to understand how it gets to the solution, ie what is or are the exact method(s) used.
Is that available anywhere ?

The final purpose being to move this project from Excel to a Java program, because it gets more and more complex.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Do the same optimization in LibreOffice Calc. Algorithms done in LibreOffice Calc are available as part of the open-source project.